# How "deliver_order" function geting value of name?

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, callback

```js
function take_order(name, callback1) {
  console.log("order has been taken.");
  callback1(name);
}

function prosess_order(name, callback2) {
  console.log(`prosesing order for ${name}.`);
  callback2(name);
}

function deliver_order(name) {
  console.log(`deliver to ${name}.`);
}

take_order("Mohiul", function (name) {
  prosess_order(name, function (name) {
    deliver_order(name);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

How "deliver_order" function geting value of name?How is it printing with name value? Please explain.(I found this code from a tutorial)

Comment: What did the tutorial say? The functions all take name as a parameter and only the first actually receives the string, the others are passed using the name variable. This is JS 101

Answer (score 1):

In this what is happening is a below

The take_order function is being executed with name argument as "Mohiul"

The take order function is calling the below anonymous function

```
function (name) {
  prosess_order(name, function (name) {
    deliver_order(name);
  });
}
```

which receives name value from the take_order function and it passes down to prosess_order function.

The prosess_order function calls the below anonymous function and passes the name argument

```
function (name) {
    deliver_order(name);
  }
```

The anonymous function calls the deliver_order function passing the name variable

This is how deliver_order function receive name value

You would also need to know the concept Closures in javascript which will help to understand more

[Here](https://medium.com/@digitaldaswani/closures-in-javascript-8ab46b78fccc) you can read more about that